# findstr for filename in win7 batch file

Tags: batch-file, pipeline, findstr

I'm kind of struggling with the following search.
I need to look for files which are misplaced in wrong folders. I have the following testing structure (in reality it is hudreds of folders):

```
C:\test2\John\John_phone.txt
C:\test2\Mary\John_address.txt
C:\test2\Mary\Mary_address.txt
C:\test2\Mary\Mary_phone.txt
C:\test2\Mary\Peter_address.txt
```

The files John_address.txt and Peter_address.txt are misplaced in Mary's folder. I want to check Mary's folder for any misplaced files and list them in a separate log file. So for the example above the log would contain the names (paths) of the two misplaced files, The deciding identifier is the person's name. I have this piece of code:

```
@echo off
cls
set /p name="Specify the name: "
::forfiles /p "%CD%\%name%" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c echo @path">>log.txt
forfiles /p "%CD%\%name%" /s /m "| findstr /i /v "\*%name%*"" /c "cmd /c echo @path">>log.txt
pause
```

The commented line for forfiles works (lists all files in the folder), so I have an issue with findstr: ERROR: Files of type "| findstr /i /v *Mary*" not found.
The /v switch with findstr should find all files that do not contain the specified name, but obviously I'm doing something wrong while using it as input for forfiles.
I don't want to use the dir command since it lists additional information and I need to integrate the output into larger log file (I need to get only the path of the misplaced file).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: Would it be easier to write the code if the correct file name would be fixed like this?

```
All_data_%NAME%_new.txt
```

The stuff before and after the name would be fixed and this format of the file name would be the only correct option, so anything else would have to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rootFolder=c:\test2"

    ( for /d %%z in ("%rootFolder%\*"
      ) do for %%y in ("%%~fz\*"
      ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~ny"
      ) do if /i not "%%~nxz"=="%%a" echo %%~fy
    ) > log.txt
```

This will iterate the files under each of the folders testing if their name starts with the same string that the folder name.

**edited** the original proposed solution does not work as intended, so, removed

**edited** - as the name of the file has not a fixed format, and the name of the folder can be in any place, this can be used

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rootFolder=c:\test2"

    rem create a temporary file to hold the patterns to match against the list 
    rem of files to determine if it is correctly placed

    set "patterns=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%.tmp"
    > "%patterns%" (
        for /d %%a in ("%rootFolder%\*") do echo(\\%%~nxa\\[^^\\]*%%~nxa[^^\\]*
    ) 

    rem Get the list of files, and filter to only get those that do not match
    rem the generated patterns

    dir /s /b /a-d "%rootFolder%\*" ^
        | findstr /r /i /c:"%rootFolder:\=\\%\\[^\\]*\\."  ^
        | findstr /r /i /e /v /g:"%patterns%" ^
    > log.txt

    rem Patterns file is no longer needed
    del "%patterns%" >nul 2>nul
```

Comment: Hi @mc-nd, thanks for the answer. This works partially. The above batch lists only c:\test2\Mary\John_address.txt, however, it doesn't list Peter_address.txt - Peter's folder is not in the root. Also, it should work list files that are totally misnamed like address_Mary.txt or Mray_address.txt. I can grab the list of correct names for a loop from a list using for /f %%i in (names_list.txt) do (... The users can't change the folder names, but they can upload anything they want. I see I should have specified this earlier. Thanks.

Comment: @karl, There was an BIG error in the pipe solution. Removed. The simple solution sould work without problems. Anyway i will try to solve it under the original idea. Thank you.

Comment: @karl, answer updated. A little more flexible file/folder match is included.

Comment: this seem to be what I was looking for. I will need to run some more tests but it looks like it dies the job. Thanks for help a nd for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

this should help provided that comparison is case sensitive

```
for /f "delims=.'_\ tokens=2,3,*" %%a in ('forfiles /s /m *.txt /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do if NOT "%%a"=="%%b" @echo "%%a\%%b_%%c
```